# Error in retrieving data using JPA : No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: oracle, hibernate, exception, jpa, jdbc

I am using the following code to retrieve data.

```
String query = "SELECT CLIENT_NAME FROM USER_TABLE WHERE USER_ID='10'";
Query qry = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
List<Object> data = null;
try {
 data = query.getResultList();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   LOGGER.error("Exception in Database data retrieval ", ex);
   throw ex;
}
```

Issue with this code is it works fine in my development environment, but not in production.
And I get the exception like

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
```

I have checked it, and then its found out that, its because my field CLIENT_NAME is of type `nvarchar2`. So I did typcast my nvarchar and used the following query

```
String query = "SELECT cast(CLIENT_NAME as varchar(100)) FROM USER_TABLE WHERE USER_ID='10'";
```

And it works fine in two environment. But the issue is that it not displaying some char( for example `ű` is shown as `¿`) in production environment. I am using oracle in back end. Here in development i use 11g and and in production it is 10g. I think it is related to the versions. Is there any other fix for this issue?

Comment: Have you set hibernate-dialect in persistence.xml? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html

Comment: <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.convertNcharLiterals" value="true"/>


Shows my persistence.xml

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider newer version of dialect like Oracle10gDialect, as OracleDialect defaults to version 8 I believe.

Also see this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/global.htm#CHDHHJDB

It has some additional configuration for jdbc. And as of 10g jdbc driver doesn't have complete support for nchar.